# How can you determine the rails.root to differentiate between localhost and the web server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up a link that is correct when in development mode on localhost and also when the app is running on the web server. I tried to use the following and put it in a link_to

```
 $link = Rails.root.to_s + "/complaints/" + @complaint.id.to_s
```

I got a link similar to

```
C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints/complaints/22
```

which did not work.  It should be http://localhost:3000/complaints/22

I worked around that by using the following code:

```
 if request.port == '3000'    
       $link = "http://localhost:3000/complaints/" + @complaint.id.to_s    
     else
       $link = "http://web:" + request.port.to_s + "/complaints/" + @complaint.id.to_s    
     end
```

The else statement uses the webserver name and inserts the port number that rails app is running on plus the path to the particular complaint. While that works, I thought that there might be a cleaner solution along the lines of Rails.root that would show the link properly regardless of if you are on localhost or the web server.

Comment: Try using `root_url`. Even better, use the [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) helper for your named route:

`<%= link_to "link_here", complaints_url(@complaint) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails.root` gives the (file system) path to the rails application root directory, not the url. Both are two different things.

Also you don't want to hardcode the urls, as it is difficult to adapt to the changes in the application.

The preferred way to generate urls is:

- to use the named url helpers that are auto/dynamically generated based on the routes defined in the `config/routes.rb` file in combination with `link_to` method (or)
- by using the `url_for` helper method, which is the work horse behind the `link_to`

By following either of the above methods, urls will auto adjust to your application changes. Read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info.